# Batch photomerge in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing, panorama

I am trying to apply photomerge on multiple files. The idea is that I have three folders, each including image1 to imageX, and I want to stitch image1 of each folder together, image2 of each together, etc until imageX.
I have tried to look for scripts but it sounds like none of those I could find are used on files organized this way. I am also very uncomfortable with JavaScript (never used before this), so trying to tinker the scripts myself gave no result.
Is there any method which doesn't require a script and/or any script which would work out ?

Comment: Are you trying to make a HDR Panoramic? Do these questions help? [Batch Photomerge - Only Process Images in Folder with Specific Title](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/129569/batch-photomerge-only-process-images-in-folder-with-specific-title) and [Multiple Panorama Automation in Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/125106/multiple-panorama-automation-in-photoshop?newreg=be233945a4234130bce0de2f35a47bb0). Outside of Photoshop, PTGui does this without scripts, but I am not sure you can do batch processing without paying for the full product.

Comment: How large a number is X? I mean if it's not too many images it might be faster to just get it done "manually" than to write a script.

Comment: ( also if you're very uncomfortable with JS it makes sense to find someone who isn't)

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for your help ! I've used the solution proposed by AndrewH, modified the script they were using, coupled with a python script to organize my images differently, and managed to get it done, thank you so much ! It is a lot of images (right now, 18657, but this is only a trial, I am actually adding frames from videos together), so manually was really not an option...