# Batch Photomerge Save Error

Tags: photoshop-scripting

Using a batch Photomerge workflow (per [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/129569/batch-photomerge-only-process-images-in-folder-with-specific-title) I asked a few years ago), I sometimes get the following error, which hangs the entire process and requires redoing the entire batch:

[image: error message]

When I asked the previous question, I was running Photoshop CS6 and have since upgraded to CC 2019, so I assume the save functionality changed in the interim.  Being unfamiliar with scripting, I am at a loss where to start.

The script is as follows:

```
// https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/125106/multiple-panorama-automation-in-photoshop
// https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/129569/batch-photomerge-only-process-images-in-folder-with-specific-title
var runphotomergeFromScript = true; // must be before Photomerge include
//@includepath "/C/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2018/Presets/Scripts/"
//@include "Photomerge.jsx"
//@show include

var psdOpts = new PhotoshopSaveOptions();
psdOpts.embedColorProfile = true;
psdOpts.alphaChannels = true;
psdOpts.layers = true;

(function()
{
    var workFolder = Folder.selectDialog();
    if (workFolder == null) return false;

    var folders = getSubfolders(workFolder, 'pano');

    if (folders.length == 0) return false

    for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++)
    {

        var fList = folders[i].getFiles('*.dng');
        if (fList.length == 0) continue;

        // override Photomerge.jsx settings. Default is "Auto". Uncomment to override the default.
        //photomerge.alignmentKey = "Auto";
        //photomerge.alignmentKey   = "Prsp";
        //photomerge.alignmentKey   = "cylindrical";
        //photomerge.alignmentKey   = "spherical";
        //photomerge.alignmentKey   = "sceneCollage";
        photomerge.alignmentKey = "translation"; // "Reposition" in layout dialog   

        // other setting that may need to be changed. Defaults below
        photomerge.advancedBlending = true; // 'Blend Images Together' checkbox in dialog
        photomerge.lensCorrection = true; // Geometric Distortion Correction'checkbox in dialog
        photomerge.removeVignette = true; // 'Vignette Removal' checkbox in dialog

        try
        {
            if (fList.length > 1)
            {
                photomerge.createPanorama(fList, false);
            }
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            alert(e + '\nLine: ' + e.line)
        }

        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771379/how-can-i-merge-visible-to-a-layer-in-a-photoshop-script
        activeDocument.mergeVisibleLayers();
        activeDocument.activeLayer.autoContrast(); // Apply contrast

        // saving
        var saveFile = {
            name: folders[i].name,
            path: fList[0].parent
        }

        savePSD(saveFile)
        saveJPG(saveFile)

        activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
    }
})()

function saveJPG(data)
{
    if (data.path == undefined) return false;
    data.name = data.name == undefined ? activeDocument.name : data.name;
    data.quality == undefined && data.quality = 75

    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580923/photoshop-javascript-to-resize-image-and-canvas-to-specific-not-square-sizes
    // these are our values for the END RESULT width and height (in pixels) of our image
    doc = app.activeDocument;      
    var fWidth = 1500;
    doc.resizeImage(UnitValue(fWidth,"px"),null,null,ResampleMethod.BICUBIC);

    var options = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb(),
    jpgFile = new File(data.path + '/' + data.name + '.jpg');
    options.format = SaveDocumentType.JPEG;
    options.quality = data.quality;
    activeDocument.exportDocument(jpgFile, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, options);

}

function savePSD(data)
{
    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
    var descOptions = new ActionDescriptor();
    descOptions.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID('maximizeCompatibility'), false);
    desc.putObject(charIDToTypeID('As  '), charIDToTypeID('Pht3'), descOptions);
    desc.putPath(charIDToTypeID('In  '), new File(data.path + "/" + data.name + ".psd"));
    executeAction(charIDToTypeID('save'), desc, DialogModes.NO);
} // end of savePSD()

function getSubfolders(folder, mask)
{ // folder object, RegExp or string  
    if (mask == undefined) mask = "";
    var sFolders = [];
    var targetFolders = [];
    sFolders[0] = folder;
    for (var j = 0; j < sFolders.length; j++)
    {
        var procFiles = sFolders[j].getFiles();
        for (var i = 0; i < procFiles.length; i++)
        {
            if (procFiles[i] instanceof Folder)
            {
                if (procFiles[i].fullName.search(mask) != -1) targetFolders.push(procFiles[i]);
                sFolders.push(procFiles[i]);
                getSubfolders(procFiles[i], mask);
            }
        }
    }
    return targetFolders
} // end of getSubfolders()
```

Comment: Changing the merge option to Auto seemed to fix this, though I'm still not clear on why the error is occurring.